# Measure 220V alternating current with a multimeter in DC mode

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, multimeter, voltmeter

What happens if we measure  220V AC from wall socket with a multimeter in DC mode (instead of AC)?

If I remember correctly, it should show the average value of this sinusoidal 220V, **i.e. 0V**.

Is this true with nearly all multimeters?

Comment: depends on how fast the meter performs the measurement. If only 1 millisecond, the meter may show a PEAK value, either -220volt or +220 volt. Or halfway down the sinusoid, perhaps at 45 degrees where 70.7% is an estimate, and 70.7% of 220 is 154 volts.

Comment: Typically it should/would show 0V. But/and, as this is a non standard use "anything MIGHT happen". Why do you ask?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Just out of curiosity: I was wondering if there was a system to **prevent** noobs from doing *"Let's measure this wall socket. Ok, multimeter ON, voltage measurement, OK. Humm 0V, it's ok I can touch with my fingerrrrrrshkjshuidirhyuezhihfishdfijs^@$^!$^$*

Comment: @Basj ..Very many **True RMS** meters accept only AC (they block DC). I'd suggest a lawyer representing a burnt noob could make a shambles of that meter manufacturer. A few meters *include* DC and make a proper RMS measurement that should help your concerns.

Comment: *" I was wondering if there was a system to prevent noobs from doing ..."* There is no fool proof solution, which is the reason why noobs should stay away from line voltages. "Against stupidity the gods themselves contend in vain. "

Comment: @Basj While not disagreeing with the spirit of Oldfart's warning, I'll note that systems can be implemented to increase the chances of user's not dying. They usually cost money, add cotton wool"/extra hassle to use and  will not stop some of oldfart's group slipping through. | Using the wrong tool or the right tool wrongly may always fail. If a cucumber showed no mains voltage present - is the outlet safe?  If a light meter showed .... ? You can only reasonably go so far.